# How to deploy a private git that I don't own?

Tags: git, github, deployment

I want to deploy a private repository that I do not own (but I have access to it and the owner has given me permission).
The problem is that I can't see it as a potentially deployable project when I go to sites like vercel or render to deploy it. But I can see my all my project (public and private).

First I tried to do something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIdVo.png) it didn't work so I tried on vercel to make a team and invite the owner in but I still couldn't deploy the project. (besides that making a team is not free)

If you have a solution that does not use vercel or render I am still interested.

Comment: Isn't a simple `git clone` what you need ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by `git clone`. I can't deploy it on internet using `git clone`, can I ?

Comment: Nope, but you'll get your own local copy that you'll then be able to synchronize as your wish with the original one afterwards. Being your own copy, you'll have all rights on it and be able to configure it so you can deploy it, as well as hacking it then open pull requests upstreams if you want to collaborate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, now I've understood but that means it's not possible, under any circumstances, to deploy someone else's private git without making our own copy?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "deploy", which sense may be totally different according to the platform you're working on. If you are talking about Vercel in particular, add the corresponding tag, then provide some more information about it.

Comment: What I mean by deploy is to make it accessible via the internet on a URL. And I was talking about vercel because I tried to use their service to solve my problem, not because I want to use their service in particular.